# VB.NET General function for "Format"

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

I want to remove all dependencies to Microsoft.VisualBasic from my solution.

One thing that causes me problems is the "Format" function.

Does anybody know what would be a clean solution for a replacement for the following function?

```
Private Function pDateAsString() As String

    Dim sDate As String = Format(DateAndTime.Day(DateTime.Today), "00") & Format(DateTime.Today.Month, "00") & Format(DateTime.Today.Year, "0000")

    Return sDate

End Function
```

I would really like to get a general replacement for the "Format" function, but I am not sure if one exists in the .NET framework. If it does not, I would already be grateful to know how to convert the above function.

Thank you!

Comment: `String.Format` will work for types which dont have built in formatting like DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple, use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
sDate = Date.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy") ' 20032014
```

Have a look: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)